# NextJS API Endpoints returning Internal Server Error when deployed on IIS

Tags: iis, next.js, windows-server-2012-r2, iisnode, swr

In local development, everything works as expected. Frontend calls the Nextjs API endpoints and receives the response with data.

However, when deployed to a IISNode, running on a Windows Server 2012 R2, API calls return only a Status Code 500 (Internal Server Error) response:

```
Content-Length: 21
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2022 14:33:59 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

As a side note, I've tested with the same `.env` from production, so the connection string for the database is correct and working.

Some alterations I've tryied where:

1. Adding `module.exports = {[webpackconfig], compress: false}` to `next.config.js`
2. Setting `NODE_OPTIONS='--http-server-default-timeout=0'`

As a example of the code, on the frontend:

```js
// frontend.tsx
const EscreverCartinha: NextPage = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useCallMyImplementationSWR();
  return <ReactComponents example={data} />
}

// useCallMyImplementationSWR
const fetcher = async (url: string) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    const { msg } = await res.json();
    const error = new Error(msg);
    throw error;
  }

  return res.json();
};

const useFetcher = (url: string) => {
  let { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);

  return {
    data: data,
    isLoading: !error && !data,
    isError: error,
  };
};

export function useCallMyImplementationSWR() {
  const URL = `/api/endpoint`;

  return useFetcher(URL);
}
```

And, on `pages/api/endpoint`:

```js
export default async function handler(
  _req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  await prisma.example
    .findMany()
    .then(async (exampleparam) => {
      if (example == null) throw "No results found...";
      res.status(200).json(example);
    })
    .catch(async (error: any) => {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ msg: error });
    });
}
```

Final note, on possible causes, the first request to any API endpoint in local development, using both `next dev` and `next build && next start`, are slow (max. 2~3s), but subsequent request are faster.

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error.

Comment: @samwu thanks a lot, with the tool I've found out that the problem was due my mistake by not running `prisma generate` before compiling the application... if you want, reply as answer, so I can check as the solution

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can mark solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see details about 500 error.